# How to host a console application using Hangfire to execute background tasks on the server

Tags: console-application, c#-5.0, hangfire

I have a console application which contains the logic to invoke an externally hosted web service and gets some data and updates the database. This task needs to executed on weekly basis. Hence I have setup a Task Scheduler to run the console application on weekly basis.

After going through some articles regarding other alternatives available, I came across HangFire.

I am interested to leverage Hangfire as it gives me a good way to use its dashboard to check the status of the jobs that are executed on the background.

Now if I want to use Hangfire to invoke the console application on weekly basis instead of the Task Scheduler, then how to host the console application using Hangfire on the server.

Can anyone guide me here with their inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I am rather new to Hangfire but your question does not make sense to me.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding but it sounds like you want Hangfire to act like a task scheduler - but that is not it's purpose. Hangfire exists in a running state - it does not spawn by itself. You start a program and tell that application to connect to this storage, possibly what queue to monitor and to go. Then it will query the storage you specified for any tasks it's required to do and execute them.

Now you could write a program to simply RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Process.Start("your application.exe", Cron.Weekly);

I'm not sure how graceful Hangfire is with cron jobs. If you need to restart your application 3 days later I'm not sure if it will know it will know it needs to run that task in 4 days, or if it will have cleaned up and rescheduled it for 7 days again.

Answer (score 0):

While using Hangfire to do task scheduling is not the most conventional way - official Hangfire documentation provides an [example](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-console-app.html) for this use case. Just add required jobs to the example